# Common ajax functions not work on ipad or tablet using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad, tablet

I write some ajax function in common.js.
I call those function from another file but they're not working on iPad or any tablets.
It's work on laptop, and mobiles well.
I'm using jquery.

[image: This is common function]
This is my function in common.js

```
function loadData(selector, url, searching_data = '', callback_selector = null, trigger_event = 'click', callback = 'callback', complete = null){
$(selector).load(url,searching_data,function() {
    if(complete !== null){ 
        complete();
    }
    if(callback_selector !== null){
        callback_selector.trigger(trigger_event,[callback]);
    }
});
};
```

[image: This is how I called]
This is how I called in another js file

```
loadData('.body-order-service-mid',
     BASE_URL+'getProductList',
     { 'Name' : '','DataHidden' : $('#btn-change-services').attr('data-hidden')}
);
```

Comment: Post code in text instead of images please

Comment: Thank @Musa i've edited